# How can I get content to resize when window is resize?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make menu items and it looked fine when the window was fully sized but not when it was resized. I tried to fix it but I ended up making it look worse. I'm a beginner so I am confused on what class needs to be changed in order to make this work. Now the items are all on one column and I wanted all 4 in the same row. The image is also not showing fully anymore and the heading is not within the container anymore either.
[image]
[image]

Code

```css
#menu {
  margin-top: 60px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

.menu-heading {
  font-size: 5rem;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: black;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.menu-grid {
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
}

.menu-img {
  display: flex;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left;
  background-image: url(https://i2.wp.com/www.littlefiggy.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/Swiss-Burger.jpg?resize=800%2C533);
}

.menu-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  width: calc(100% / 4);
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: white;
}

.menu-container:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 3rem black;
  transform: scale(1.07);
}

.menu-container>.menu-p {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 15px 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.menu-container>.menu-heading {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.menu-container>ol {
  margin: 15px;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  #menu {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .menu-container {
    max-width: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
  }
}

.menu-p {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu-title {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.price {
  font-size: 3rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FF4500;
}
```

```html
<div class="content" id="container">
  <section id="desc">
    <h2>Burgers Done Right</h2>
    <hr>
    <p><i>With high-quality ingredients</i></p>
  </section>
  <div>
    <img id="animated-gif" src="https://media.giphy.com/media/l0Iy1WEZpJQ6V5SVO/giphy.gif" alt="cheese burger" />
  </div>
</div>


<section id="how-its-made">
  <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/V5w1OGknhlc" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</section>
<section class="menu" id="menu">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="menu-heading">Menu</div>
    <div class="menu-grid">
      <div class="menu-hold">
        <div class="menu-container">
          <div class="menu-img">
            &nbsp;
          </div>
          <h1 class="menu-title">Swiss Mushroom Burger</h1>
          <p class="menu-p">Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
          <h3 class="price">$12</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="menu-hold">
        <div class="menu-container">
          <div class="menu-img">
            &nbsp;
          </div>
          <h1 class="menu-title">Classic Cheese Burger</h1>
          <p class="menu-p">Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
          <h3 class="price">$10</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="menu-hold">
        <div class="menu-container">
          <div class="menu-img">
            &nbsp;
          </div>
          <h1 class="menu-title">Bacon Cheeseburger</h1>
          <p class="menu-p">Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
          <h3 class="price">$12</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="menu-hold">
        <div class="menu-container">
          <div class="menu-img">
            &nbsp;
          </div>
          <h1 class="menu-title">Vegan Burger</h1>
          <p class="menu-p">Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
          <h3 class="price">$14</h3>
        </div>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and, where it says "enter image description here", **enter a description of the image**.

Answer (score -1):

The max-width property defines the maximum width of an element. If the content is smaller than the max-width it runs the code in the media query. And only screen keyword is used to prevent older browsers that do not support media queries with media features from applying the specified styles. This is just a demo code, you can change the parameter to suit your project

```css
.sample-image {
  width: 1000px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  /*Style your element below*/
  .sample-image {
    width: 500px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to explain code rather than just dumping code on people. Answers are meant to help everyone who has the same question, no matter the skill level. Explain why you chose the code you did also (e.g., why `only screen`? why `max-width: 600px`? The OP already has `max-width: 800px`)

Comment: The max-width property defines the maximum width of an element. If the content is smaller than the max-width it runs the code in the media query. And only screen: The only keyword is used to prevent older browsers that do not support media queries with media features from applying the specified styles. This is just a demo code, you can change the parameter to suit your project

Comment: Okay, let's try that again. Please [edit] your answer with an explanation. Don't add another comment. Click the [Edit] link under the answer (or any of the three in my comments) and add your explanation to the answer. Comments are often deleted; answers less often.